# Is having a lone pair sufficient and necessary for a Lewis base? What about empty orbitals and Lewis acids?

Tags: acid-base, terminology

Is any molecule with a lone pair and/or a pi bond considered a Lewis base? Also, is any molecule with an incomplete octet a Lewis acid?

Comment: The most common ones are the ones you described. I don't know about any specific rare cases though.

Answer (score 2):

No, not every molecule that has a valence lone pair is automatically a Lewis base.

For example, tin forms divalent salts such as $\ce{SnCl2}$ wherein tin is in the $\mathrm{+II}$ oxidation state and thus its electronic configuration is $\ce{[Kr]}\ \mathrm{4d^{10}\,5s^2\,5p^0}$. Even if we say that the d-electrons are not really valence electrons, since they are not really chemically accessable, you cannot deny that tin(II) has a lone pair in its 5s orbital. However, this lone pair does *not* exhibit Lewis basic properties; instead, tin(II) functions as a Lewis *acid.* The reason for that is the spherical symmetry of the s-orbital along with its notable dispersion, which means it cannot be reasonably donated in a Lewis-basic matter.

Note that the lone pair *is* accessable chemically: tin(II) can be oxidised to tin(IV) e.g. by $\ce{HgCl2}$.

---

A somewhat similar (but much more questionable!) case can be made for electron sextets and Lewis acids. NHCs are a pretty common substance class. The most generic structure is that of imidazole, but with both nitrogens substituted so that one of them bears a positive charge (the one with a double bond to the carbon sandwiched between the two). If a base is added to remove that sandwiched carbon’s proton, a carbene is generated in which said carbon is *only* bonded to the nitrogen, has an $\mathrm{sp^2}$ configured lone pair and is considered to have an empty $\mathrm{p}$ orbital. However, this carbene is *nucleophilic*, which is why they are also called *nucleophilic heterocyclic carbenes.* They react as Lewis bases with metal centres; the second generation of Grubbs’ metathesis catalysts made use of NHCs.

Of course, it is slightly debatable whether the p-orbital on that NHC carbon is truly empty. One could argue that significant electron pair donation from both nitrogens should happen.

(As a side note: radicals, while not having full octets, are typically *never* considered Lewis acids — but then, their orbital is already occupied by a single electron, so they don’t have an empty orbital that would make them a potential Lewis acid, anyway. Thus, your question should better be worded differently to explicitly exclude radicals.

Answer (score 0):

From [Wikipedia](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Lewis_acids_and_bases):

> Lewis acid is a chemical species that reacts with a Lewis base to form a Lewis adduct. A Lewis base, then, is any species that donates a pair of electrons to a Lewis acid to form a Lewis adduct.

For example, in the reaction $\ce{H3B + NH3 -> H3B-NH3}$, the $\ce{N}$ donated a pair of electrons to $\ce{B}$, so $\ce{H3B}$ is the Lewis acid and $\ce{NH3}$ is the Lewis base.

---

### Is any molecule with a lone pair and/or a pi bond considered a Lewis base?

No. For example, $\ce{CH4}$ has no lone pair or $\pi$ bond, but it is still considered a Lewis base:

$$\ce{CH4 + H+ <<=> CH5+}$$

---

### Is any molecule with a incomplete octet a Lewis acid?

No. For example, $\ce{NH4+}$ has a complete octet, but it is considered a Lewis acid:

$$\ce{NH4+ + :OH- <=>> NH3 + H2O}$$

Comment: NH4+ isn't Lewis acid in this example but Bronsted acid

Comment: @Mithoron but... but... [wikipedia says it is](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/File:Lewis_bases_and_acids.jpg)... so it must be, right

Comment: @Mithoron It can be consider as both depends on how you think about it.

Comment: Well, Wikipedia isn't always right, but if you loosen the definition, you could say it's also Lewis acid.

Comment: agree with @Mith, I would argue that proton donors *generate* the Lewis acid $\ce{H+}$ but are *not* Lewis acids themselves